# Internet Explorer unsupported get request

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, canvas, get

I got a big problem in IE (only IE, FF etc works great).

I got a canvas page: xyz.de/gewinnspiel.php?register=1.
In IE I get the following error:

> FacebookApiException: Unsupported get request. in Facebook->_graph()

Does anybody have an idea?

---

IE8

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
    ));

$loginuser = $facebook->getUser();

$userInfo           = $facebook->api("/$loginuser");
```

the $userInfo triggers the error...

Comment: What api method are you calling? what's your sample code?

Comment: Check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644513/user-opted-out-of-platform-can-post-and-is-viewable-but-not-via-the-graph-api