# User opted out of platform can post and is viewable, but not via the Graph API (Unsupported get request error)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When we try to get some wall post by Facebook's graph API, gives an error:

> "Unsupported get request.".

Facebook answered:

> This is by design and indeed due to the fact that a particular user opted out of platform in their settings. They can still post to a page's wall, viewable on the site (but not via the Graph API).
>
> To prevent user's who opt-out from being able to post to your wall, the page's settings need to be updated to set PLATFORM_OPTOUTS_CAN_POST to "false.
>
> https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/155412377991372

We don't want that users opt-out can not post in our pages.

For the users who have a opted out of platform in their settings, (they have prevented 3rd party applications from seeing their posts), what can we tell those users so the users can change their settings to allow their wall posts to be been by 3rd party applications (?)

Thanks!

Comment: `what can we tell those users so the users can change their settings to allow their wall posts to be been by 3rd party applications`-  they have opted out  by their wish! btw.. this ques is off-topic - not related to programming.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Facebook customer support resp. should be researched in their help section.


Answer (score 3):

If the user wishes to opt back in to sharing their data with applications, they can go to their Account Settings > Apps. Then change the top setting that says, "Use apps, plugins, games and websites on Facebook and elsewhere" from **Off** to **On**.